# How to change the result of my MySQL select query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query

```
select pi.identifier, pn.given_name, pn.family_name,vt.name,  cn.name as diagnosis, v.date_created, e.encounter_id
from concept as c
inner join concept_name as cn on cn.concept_id = c.concept_id
inner join obs as o on o.value_coded = c.concept_id
inner join encounter as e on o.encounter_id = e.encounter_id
inner join visit as v on e.visit_id = v.visit_id
inner join patient as p on p.patient_id = v.patient_id
inner join person as per on per.person_id = p.patient_id
inner join person_name as pn on pn.person_id = per.person_id
inner join patient_identifier as pi on pi.patient_id = p.patient_id
inner join visit_type as vt on vt.visit_type_id = v.visit_type_id
where (c.class_id = 4 or c.class_id = 11)
and
v.voided = 0
and
cn.concept_name_type = 'FULLY_SPECIFIED'
and
date(v.date_created) between '2017-10-01' and '2017-10-02'
```

This gives

```
Identifier  given_name  last_name   name    diagnosis   date_created    encounter_id
MMA001113   A   A   IGD BPJS    02-10-17 21:18  1804
MMA001113   A   A   IGD Confirmed   02-10-17 21:18  1805
MMA001113   A   A   IGD A07.0 (Balantidiasis)   02-10-17 21:18  1805
MMA001113   B   B   IGD UMUM    02-10-17 21:18  1806
MMA001113   B   B   IGD Confirmed   02-10-17 21:18  1807
MMA001113   B   B   IGD B07.0 (Balantidiasis)   02-10-17 21:18  1807
```

The 1st and 3rd row contains "BPJS" and "Umum" which is actually a `patient-type` that should apply to other rows. My expected result is like below

```
Identifier  given_name  last_name   name    diagnosis   date_created    encounter_id    patient_type
MMA001113   A   A   IGD Confirmed   02-10-17 21:18  1805    BPJS
MMA001113   A   A   IGD A07.0 (Balantidiasis)   02-10-17 21:18  1805    BPJS
MMA001113   B   B   IGD Confirmed   02-10-17 21:18  1807    UMUM
MMA001113   B   B   IGD B07.0 (Balantidiasis)   02-10-17 21:18  1807    UMUM
```

I can exclude the types from the result row, but I need to bring it up as a result column.

How can I modify my SQL query to achieve that ?

Comment: Add the appropriate filter to your where clause.

Comment: Care to show a hint through some samples?

Comment: It's not clear from your query what your data looks like. Are you saying that one or more of the tables contains mutliple rows per given_name with the first row per given name is BPJS or UMUM and is a patient_type which should be assigned to all the subsequent given_names?

Comment: @P.Salmon correct

Comment: I think you need to add a where cn.name not in ('BPJS','UMUM') and add and inner join concept_name as cn1 on cn1.concept_id = c.concept_id and cn1.name in ('BPJS','UMUM')